# Difficulty solving module attribute error in Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, error-handling, module

I'm learning selenium right now. My selenium version is 4.9.1. When I try importing and using the full name of the module, it gives this error -

```
selenium.webdriver has no attribute find_element
```

This is the code I've written:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

browser.maximize_window()

browser.get("https://www.asurascans.com/?s=Beast+Burn")

element = webdriver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "surprise")

action = ActionChains(browser)

action.click(on_element = element)

action.perform()

browser.quit()

print("succesfull run!")
```

I have tried changing it to -

```
webdriver.chrome.webdriver.find_element
```

But, I get the same error as before.

Comment: I think that should be `browser.find_element(...)`.

Comment: now it shows NameError: name 'By' is not defined from the line element = webdriver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "surprise")

Comment: Please understand that the SO Q&A format is not well suited to an ongoing tutorial session where fixing one error just gets the interpreter a few lines further down in the code before it hits another. But you're in luck: I see that @Shawn anticipated your next question before you asked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly suggested to you in the comment by @BoarGules, change `webdriver.find_element(...)` to `browser.find_element(...)`

In addition to that I see few more issues:

1. I do not see `By` import in your code, but you have used it in your code. You need to import `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`
2. Since you are using selenium `v4.9.1`, you don't need `WebDriverManager` to handle browser drivers, your code can be simplified as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("https://www.asurascans.com/?s=Beast+Burn")
element = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "surprise")
action = ActionChains(browser)
action.click(on_element=element)
action.perform()
browser.quit()
print("succesfull run!")
```